# Sqoop avro java column mapping from file

Tags: hdfs, sqoop, avro

I am using sqoop to export data from oracle to hdfs in avro format using below query

```
sqoop import --connection-param-file ora.properties --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/servicename --username <user> --password-file <password-file> --map-column-java TRADE_NUM=Integer,STRATEGY_NUM=Integer,COMMISSION_AMT=Double,TRADE_INPUT_DT=String --query "SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE \$CONDITIONS " --target-dir <location on hdfs> --delete-target-dir --split-by TRADE_NUM --verbose --compress --as-avrodatafile
```

I would like to pass the mapping (--map-column-java) from a file rather than providing from the command line, is there an option for doing it, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the options file to pass parameters to Sqoop. According to the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1762730), you can use the option `--options-file` to specify the file containing the arguments.

> When using Sqoop, the command line options that do not change from invocation to invocation can be put in an options file for convenience. An options file is a text file where each line identifies an option in the order that it appears otherwise on the command line (...) 
>   Option files can be specified anywhere in the command line as long as the options within them follow the otherwise prescribed rules of options ordering.